# Saving manyToMany data cakephp3

Tags: forms, orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm struggling about this issue for a while. I have three tables `prestation`, `tools` and `prestation_tools`. And my entities are linked as follow :

```
#ToolsTable
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('tools');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsToMany('Prestation', [
        'joinTable' => 'prestation_tools',
        'foreignKey' => 'tools_id'
    ]);
}

#PrestationTable
public function initialize(array $config)
{
     parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('prestation');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->belongsToMany('Tools', [
        'through' => 'PrestationTools'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Competences', [
        'through' => 'PrestationCompetences'
    ]);
}

#PrestationToolsTable
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('prestation_tools');
    $this->displayField('prestation_id');
    $this->primaryKey(['prestation_id', 'tools_id']);

    $this->belongsTo('Prestation', [
        'foreignKey' => 'prestation_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Tools', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tools_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

And of my form is :

```
<?= $this->Form->input("Prestation.Tools.1.tools_id", [
          'label' => false,
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => $tools,
          'empty' => "Sélectionner l'outil 1",
        'templates' => [
          'inputContainer' => '{{content}}'
        ],
        'class' => 'form-control',

          ]) ?>
    <label >Spécifications de l'outil 1</label>
    <?= $this->Form->textarea('Prestation.Tools.1.details', [
          'templates' => [
            'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{content}}</div>'
          ],
          'class' => 'form-control',
          'placeholder' => 'Spécifications de l\'outil',
            'label' => 'Spécifications de l\'outil'
          ]) ?>
```

When trying to save from `PrestationController`, on `prestation` record is saved. Can anyone help me ?

**Update**
My `PrestationController`'s `add()` action looks like this :

```
public function add(){
    #...
    $prestation = $this->Prestation->patchEntity($prestation, $this->request->data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'Tools',
                    'Competences'
                ]
            ]);
    #...
}
```

Comment: Have you used the 'associated' key as described in the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities)?

Comment: @GregSchmidt, yes. Look at my update.